# How to synchronise with Facebook that username and password are valid or not?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am creating an application in which I am trying to add Facebook account in app. What I wish to do is when user enter their username and password my application should call some Facebook API or any other thing by which it will confirm that the user credentials are correct for Facebook.

Then the API will return some message by which I can add account or give an alert that credentials are not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to login using the username/password directly to the api.
use facebook connect instead.

Comment: I only want to know that the username and password are correct or not thats it. Right now I don't want to get login. I had created my own view with two textFields. Can't I call any thing for checking only. Because I am storing username and password in sqlite database of my app.

Comment: Your storing people facebook logins?

Comment: Actually the database is in application and for the person who will use application can store his credentials in application. This is what requirement... If not possible then can we check for username only?..